# Using moment.js to determine if moment() is before, during or after a specific time block

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around moment.js. Essentially what I want to do is determine if the current time is before, between or after a certain time block. I can't figure out if I should use an array for my specific time blocks, or an object, or maybe I'm going about this all wrong... Any guidance would be awesome.

Comment: (I'm not sure that's your question, so I'm adding it as a commentary) With moment.js you can access the methods isAfter, isSame and isBefore: [moment.js documentaiton about that](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)

Comment: Do you care about the date? You could have a time block which starts today at 11:00 pm and ends tomorrow at 01:15 am.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the format of your input to moment js and then you can compare them:

```js
let momentTime = moment("13:30", 'HH:mm');
let laterMomentTime = moment("15:00", 'HH:mm');

if(momentTime.isBefore(laterMomentTime)){
  console.log("Yes 1:30 pm is earlier");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply. Really what I'm stuck with is using time instead of date. Particularly using isBefore, isAfter and isBetween. Any tips would be awesome!

Comment: @alexgignilliat I've updated my answer. Let me know if this is what you need.